# Are there any symbols when compiling a portable class library that can be used with preprocessor directives

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I have added a portable class library to my solution in which has a global file that is linked to all the projects.  This global file contains the assembly level attributes such as version, culture, and Com visibility.  The problem I want to solve is that some attributes such as ComVisible are not valid in the context of a PCL so is there any symbol that used with #if to prevent that attribute for being included at build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcame this issue by adding stub/dummy attribute classes to a compact framework project that mimic their FCL counterparts:

```
// Shared source file
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Foo
{
}

// Dummy class in portable project -- exists only to facilitate compilation of the shared source file
namespace System
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTarget.Class)]
    public class ComVisibleAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public ComVisibleAttribue(bool visible)
        {
            // Dummy implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Now the shared source code file will compile in both projects without any modification to the code, and without any preprocessor directives.

Comment: Matt thanks for thinking outside of the box!  This is a viable solution as well.

Comment: @MattDavey Sorry for being late to the party, but I don't think this is a recommendable solution (correct me if I am wrong). The `ComVisibleAttribute` is not available in PCL, but it *is* available in most of the targets. So whenever you want to use the PCL within a specific target, for example a .NET application, you will get a name clash. I think you can work around this issue using the `TypeForwardedToAttribute`, but I do not have experience in doing this myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your own pre-processor symbols within the build properties. I don't know if there are any specific ones by *default* for portable class libraries, but it wouldn't be hard to specify one in each configuration for your project.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I was looking for a built-in but this makes sense and saves time!